# NavmeshAgent car rotation match to slope

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

[my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La9PE.png)

So that white little cube is destination of car agent. Its working perfect on flat but if there is a slope agent's rotation is not changing. How can I do that?

Comment: you need to give more information and context about what you are doing what is the problem (code samples etc.).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question with a seemingly useful answer to your situation.

[NavmeshAgent player not parallel to slope of hill when moving over hill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117631/navmeshagent-player-not-parallel-to-slope-of-hill-when-moving-over-hill)

The gist is, NavMeshAgents don't do this themselves. You will have to program that in yourself.